# Unidentified #2 bag from 2007 with black and yellow pieces and many black 1x2 clip pieces!

Tags: set-identification

It's driving me crazy! I recently purchased LEGO pieces from a local Goodwill. It looks like there's several Star Wars sets from 2007-2008 that are missing lots of pieces. I was assuming this bag was from a Star Wars set, but I'm not seeing anything that resembles the yellow pieces.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to Bricks.SE, Amy!

Indeed, this bag is not from a Star Wars set. It is from Exo-Force set [8117 Storm Lasher](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=8117-1#T=P) from 2007. This set contains both the 2 yellow pincer-like blades as well as the concave windscreen in trans-black, and many of the hinge pieces displayed in the left bottom corner of your picture.

[image]

Comment: Ahhh! Finally! I was looking up the exo force sets too, but i wasnt having any luck! I guess im missing way more pieces than i thought. Thank you so much!!